# How to set the width of a VLC player

Tags: javascript, sapui5, vlc, rtsp

I am using Chrome 25.0.1364.160 to play an rtsp stream:

```
<html:object type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org/" id='vlc' events='false' style="width: 300; height: 300px" width="300" height="300">
    <html:param name='mrl' value='rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov' />
    <html:param name='volume' value='50' />
    <html:param name='autoplay' value='true' />
    <html:param name='loop' value='false' />
    <html:param name='fullscreen' value='false' />
    <html:param name='controls' value='true' />
    <html:embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" name="vlc" />
</html:object>
```

**But the video image only shows about a third of it.**

When I inspect the element, the width is right. And the width of container is 423px.

I have tried:

- `style="width: 300; height: 300px" width="300" height="300"`
- `style="width: 300; height: 300px"`
- `width="300" height="300"`

QA：

Q: Why I am using xhtml?

A: Because I am using XML View in sapUI5

Q: Why I am using such an old Chrome?

A: Because this code in Firefox only plays sound, not any image, and new Chrome didn't support VLC(NPAPI), I've tried vxgplayer, but it has trouble in HTTPS. I just want to find a quick way to show my RTSP.

Comment: FYI: `style="width: 300;"` has no meaning. You have to put a unit. 300 what? As in `style="width: 300px;"` (300 pixels). In CSS the only valid non unit number is 0.

Comment: @gman, sorry , it‘s a typo, I tried style="width: 300px; height: 300px" and it's working now.  And I changed it back to width: 300, the video is still working, so I thinks this error is still mainly caused by in compatible with Chrome 25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to GoogleChrome_x86_44.0.2403.157, and it's fixed.